# Changing order of legends in ComplexHeatmap

Tags: r, heatmap, bioconductor

**Cross-post:** [issues/557](https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap/issues/557)

I was not able to find a solution for changing the order of the legends in ComplexHeatmap.

### Example

```r
library(ComplexHeatmap)

set.seed(100)

ha <- HeatmapAnnotation(foo = rep(c("gr1", "gr2"), each = 5), annotation_label = c("col_an"))

ra <- HeatmapAnnotation(pt = rep(letters[1:2], each = 5), which = "row", annotation_label = c("row_an"))

Heatmap(matrix(rnorm(100), 10), name = "mat", top_annotation = ha, left_annotation = ra)
```

[image]

**Question:** How to put legends in the following order, from top to bottom?

1. `col_an`
2. `row_an`
3. `mat`

### SessionInfo

```r
xfun::session_info()
```

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6, RStudio 1.3.1056

Locale: en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / C / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8

Package version:
  assertthat_0.2.1     backports_1.1.8      base64enc_0.1.3      BiocGenerics_0.34.0  circlize_0.4.10     
  cli_2.0.2            clue_0.3-57          cluster_2.1.0        colorspace_1.4-1     compiler_4.0.2      
  ComplexHeatmap_2.5.4 crayon_1.3.4         curl_4.3             digest_0.6.25        ellipsis_0.3.1      
  evaluate_0.14        fansi_0.4.1          GetoptLong_1.0.2     GlobalOptions_0.1.2  glue_1.4.1          
  graphics_4.0.2       grDevices_4.0.2      grid_4.0.2           highr_0.8            htmltools_0.5.0     
  IRanges_2.22.2       jsonlite_1.7.0       knitr_1.29           lifecycle_0.2.0      magick_2.4.0        
  magrittr_1.5         markdown_1.1         methods_4.0.2        mime_0.9             parallel_4.0.2      
  pillar_1.4.6         pkgconfig_2.0.3      png_0.1-7            purrr_0.3.4          R.cache_0.14.0      
  R.methodsS3_1.8.0    R.oo_1.23.0          R.utils_2.9.2        RColorBrewer_1.1-2   Rcpp_1.0.5          
  rematch2_2.1.2       rjson_0.2.20         rlang_0.4.7          rmarkdown_2.3        rprojroot_1.3.2     
  rstudioapi_0.11      S4Vectors_0.26.1     shape_1.4.4          stats_4.0.2          stats4_4.0.2        
  stringi_1.4.6        stringr_1.4.0        styler_1.3.2         tibble_3.0.3         tinytex_0.25        
  tools_4.0.2          utf8_1.1.4           utils_4.0.2          vctrs_0.3.2          withr_2.2.0         
  xfun_0.16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution provided by the author:

```r
set.seed(100)

ha <- HeatmapAnnotation(foo = rep(c("gr1", "gr2"), each = 5), annotation_label = c("col_an"),
    annotation_name_side = "left")
ra <- HeatmapAnnotation(pt = rep(letters[1:2], each = 5), which = "row", annotation_label = c("row_an"))

ht = ha %v% Heatmap(matrix(rnorm(100), 10), name = "mat", left_annotation = ra)
draw(ht, merge_legend = TRUE, column_dend_side = "top")
```

https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap/issues/557#issuecomment-673404750